# Alamofire 5 request ServerTrustEvaluating issue

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I upgraded to Alamofire 5 and now got the issue when making requests:

> "Server trust evaluation failed due to reason: A ServerTrustEvaluating value is required for host demo.mXXme.com but none was found."

I setup my manager with `DisabledEvaluator` in this way:

```
let manager = Session(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: [ "demo.mXXme.com": DisabledEvaluator()]))
```

As I understand `DisabledEvaluator` should disable any server trust checks.
But I still got the issue.

Does any one have ideas how to make my requests work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, `ServerTrustManager` requires that all hosts must have their trusts evaluated. So if you make a request to a domain you don't have in your `ServerTrustManager`, this error will be produced. These host strings are also case sensitive, so it may not find a match if the domains don't match exactly. I would suggest fixing the matching issue first, but you can disable the required evaluation of all hosts by initializing your `ServerTrustManager` with an addition parameter:

```swift
ServerTrustManager(allHostsMustBeEvaluated: false, 
                   evaluators: ["demo.mXXme.com": DisabledEvaluator()])
```

But like I said, you should investigate the matching issue first.

Comment: You are right the issue was in matching domains. I found that Alamofire doesn't handle wildcards by default, so the hosts `*.mXXme.com` and `demo.mXXme.com` are not equal.

Comment: This is not working in our app. I also tried with `DefaultTrustEvaluator` But no use. Looks like I have to do SSL pinning.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `wildcards`, you need to create a subclass of `ServerTrustManager` using `Alamofire 5`:

```
class WildcardServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustManager {
    override func serverTrustEvaluator(forHost host: String) throws -> ServerTrustEvaluating? {
        if let policy = evaluators[host] {
            return policy
        }
        var domainComponents = host.split(separator: ".")
        if domainComponents.count > 2 {
            domainComponents[0] = "*"
            let wildcardHost = domainComponents.joined(separator: ".")
            return evaluators[wildcardHost]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then, in the implementation:

```
public lazy var session: Session = {
    let configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300

    let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
        "*.yourdomain.com": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator()
    ]

    let manager = WildcardServerTrustPolicyManager(evaluators: evaluators)

    return Session(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: manager)
}()
```

Now you can use a certificate with `wildcard` (`*.example.com`) for all of your subdomains.

For more information:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#subclassing-server-trust-policy-manager

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1335